# xz: OOM when compressing 1TB .tar

Tags: linux-kernel, out-of-memory, multithreading, xz

I'm trying to compress a large archive with multi-threading enabled, however, my system keeps freezing up and runs out of memory.

```
OS: Manjaro 21.1.0 Pahvo    
Kernel: x86_64 Linux 5.13.1-3-MANJARO
Shell: bash 5.1.9
RAM: 16GB
```

```
|swapon|
NAME      TYPE   SIZE   USED   PRIO
/swapfile file   32G    0B     -2
```

I've tried this with a `/swapfile` 2x the amount of RAM I have (32GB) but the system would always freeze once >90% of total RAM has been used, and would seem to not make use of the /swapfile.

```
|xz --info-memory|
Total amount of physical memory (RAM) : 15910 MiB
Memory usage limit for compression: Disabled
Memory usage limit for decompression: Disabled
```

I'm new to using `xz` so please bear with me, but is there a way to globally enable the memory usage limiter and for the Total amount of physical memory (RAM) to take into account the space made available by `/swapfile`?

Comment: What about --memlimit-compress=limit and/or --memlimit-decompress=limit?

Comment: xz really does excellent compression, but at high computational cost. I'd advise you to try `zstd` in a non-crazy compression setting, l do `zstd -10` and rarely get files that are significantly larger than their xz brethren – just take a tenth of the time to compress and decompress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `man xz`:

> Memory usage
>
> Especially  users  of older systems may find the possibility of
> very large memory usage annoying.  To prevent uncomfortable surprises,
> xz has a built-in memory usage limiter, which is disabled by default.
>
> The memory usage limiter can be enabled with the command line option
> `--memlimit=limit`.  Often it is more convenient to enable the limiter
> by default by setting the  environment  variable  `XZ_DEFAULTS`.

Comment: Works by setting either `--memlimit` or `--threads` to a lower number, thanks.